# how to handle android.view.inflateexception Binary XML file line #5

Tags: android, inflate-exception

so I am developing and I came a cross an inflate exception and I don't know what to do with it.

**log cat:**

```
03-09 16:33:12.018    8201-8201/org.aron.modiryar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.aron.modiryar, PID: 8201
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.aron.modiryar/org.aron.modiryar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at `com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at org.aron.modiryar.fragment.MainMenu.onCreateView(MainMenu.java:41)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
        at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
```

and this is my android **manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.aron.modiryar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" android:enabled="true" android:name=".system.Initialize"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                   android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and my layout which can not be inflated is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:id="@+id/mainmenulayer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:visibility="visible"  style="@style/MainMenu">
   <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_title_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_title_collect" style="@style/RowMenuTitleText" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_inbox">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount" android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible" android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:id="@+id/menu_inbox_text" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_inbox" style="@style/RowMenuText" />
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_inbox"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_title_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_title_focuse_on" style="@style/RowMenuTitleText" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_today">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_today" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_today"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_next_action">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_next_action" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_next"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_tomorrow">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_tomorrow" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_tomorrow"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_calendar">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_calendar" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_scheduled"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_someday">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_sameday" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_someday"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_waitingfor">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_menu_row_count_margin_left">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/total_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/TotalCount"></LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/overdue_count" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" style="@style/OverDueCount" android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_waitingfor" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_waiting"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_divider_line_height" style="@style/MainMenuLine"/>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_divider_line_height" style="@style/MainMenuLineWhite"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_project">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_project" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_project"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_Goal">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_goal" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_goal"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_responsibility">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_responsibility" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_responsibility"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_vision">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_vision" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_inbox"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_divider_line_height" style="@style/MainMenuLine"/>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_divider_line_height" style="@style/MainMenuLineWhite"/>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_reference">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_reference" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_inbox"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_trash">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_trash" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_trash"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_done">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_done" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_trash"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_routine">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_routine" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_inbox"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_height" android:orientation="horizontal" style="@style/RowMenu" android:id="@+id/menu_tags">
            <org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/menu_tags" style="@style/RowMenuText"/>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/main_menu_row_icon_height" android:src="@drawable/home_tags"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

as you may or may not see there is some `linearlayouts` with same ids but I know for fact that's not my problem.
the real problem is app runs on earlier android versions but not on higher ones.
and I already tried changing target sdk in android manifest.

so what am I missing please help.

```
public class TextView extends android.widget.TextView {
public TextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setTypeface(Config.getDefaultTypeFace(context));
}

public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setTypeface(Config.getDefaultTypeFace(context));
}

public TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.setTypeface(Config.getDefaultTypeFace(context));
}
}
```

Comment: the mess you are seeing is in layout and my problem should be some where in there so i can't delete some of it.

Comment: My layouts are all properly indented. Anyway, **this** component looks very suspicious, to me: `org.aron.modiryar.view.TextView`

Comment: I checked it before seems like there is no problem in it but I'll now add the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after about 8 hours working on it i found out what my problem was, and I am posting this answer so it may help someone else.

1- as you can see in stack trace my problem was in MainMenu.java where it was inflating, so my problem is in the layout inflated.

2- the XML file line 5 is in that layout.it might seem so innocent but it has an style.

3- in that style it has dimension witch only is defined in values-large that was my problem.I had to define it in all other dimen values to work.

note: my problem was not in SDK version it was in device size.
hope this help someone else.